# Conditional formatting results in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, format, conditional-statements

Can I use the index data below:

```
=INDEX(E10:E12;MATCH(".";F10:F12;0))*1,25
```

to be used in conditional formatting for a "greater than" case?

The format result is not always correct, so I do not know what is the problem.

Comment: Is should be possible to do that - are you applying that formula to a single cell or a range? If it's the latter then you probably need to make the references in the formula absolute - unless you want the formula to change for each cell?

Comment: you are trying find only . why? and 1,25 means 1.25 right?

Comment: @ZAT, yes, it is, as in a Dutch system, so need to use 1,25 as 1.25